# How to open page in man with title of several words?

Tags: linux, manpage

In `man git` page I read this string:

```
See gittutorial(7) to get started, then see Everyday Git[1] for a useful minimum 
set of commands. The Git User's Manual[2] has a more in-depth introduction.
```

Titles `Everyday Git[1]` and `Git User's Manual[2]` has several words separated by space, how to open them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are not `man` pages, but external documents. The number in square brackets references the notes section at the end of the document, where the location of these files is given.

Answer (score 1):

Those are the references not to the man pages, but to the external resources listed in the end of the file (note the square brackets):

```
    1. Everyday Git
       file:///usr/share/doc/git-doc/everyday.html

    2. Git User’s Manual
       file:///usr/share/doc/git-doc/user-manual.html
```